# jQuery - Animate on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I know this is likely to be closed as a duplicate, but still I didn't manage to find an answer to my problem in all the similar questions.

I want to `animate()` an element on my page (through jQuery, you had guessed) on mouse hover. What I did was:

```
$('blockquote').hover(function() {
    console.log($(this));
    $(this).animate({textSize: '+=10px'}, 500);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({textSize: '-=10px'}, 500);
});
```

The `console.log` logs this:

```
[blockquote#daily_quote, context: blockquote#daily_quote, jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…]
```

Both functions inside `hover` get called, `$(this)` gets logged but nothing animates.

Comment: does textSize really there...??? if not then use fontSize.

Comment: what is blockquote ? does it mean class or div or anything else ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `fontSize`:

```
$('blockquote').hover(function() {
    // console.log($(this));
    $(this).animate({fontSize: '+=10px'}, 500);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({fontSize: '-=10px'}, 500);
});
```

Comment: Ok, that fixes this, but then if I try to change `'background-color'` property it doesn't work again...

Comment: @whatyouhide use only background property

Comment: @whatyouhide If you want to animate colors you should load jQuery UI.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thank you. Flagged as not a real question.

Answer (score 1):

```
This may be help you.
$('blockquote').hover(function() {

        $(this).animate({left: '+=10px'}, 700);
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({left: '-=10px'}, 700);
    });
```

you can use any property instead of left